# django tastypie: how do I control RelatedField "fullness" with url parameter?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using django tastypie to publish a model with a Related (ToOne) field to another model resource. The uri is:
`/api/map/?format=json`

I want to let the client include a `full_pages` url parameter to get the full related page resource: `/api/map/?full_pages=1&format=json`

I don't really understand the [Relationship Fields docs](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.9.12/fields.html?highlight=apifield#relationship-fields), but I made a `get_full` callable:

```
def get_full(bundle):
    if bundle.request.GET.get('full_pages', 0):
        return True
    return False
```

I tried passing the callable to the `full` argument of `ToOneField`:

```
from tastypie.contrib.gis import resources as gis_resources

class MapResource(gis_resources.ModelResource):
    page = fields.ToOneField('pages.api.PageResource', 'page', full=get_full)
```

But when I check with pdb, `get_full` is never invoked.

So then I tried creating a custom `FillableToOneField` with a `full` attribute:

```
class FillableToOneField(fields.ToOneFIeld):
    full = get_full

class MapResource(ModelResource):
    page = FillableToOneField('pages.api.PageResource', 'page')
```

Again, `get_full` is never invoked.

Is there a better, easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this under the `dehydrate` method as follows.

```
class MapResource(ModelResource):
    page = fields.ToOneField('pages.api.PageResource', 'page')

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if bundle.request.Get.get('full_pages'):
            self.page.full = True
        return bundle
```

and have them send a request as `/api/map/?full_pages=True&format=json`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - the GET param has no effect on the page full attribute. :(

Comment: @groovecoder I did test this before posting it. Do you get any errors ?

Comment: No errors; I'm actually extending tastypie.contrib.gis.resources.ModelResource if that makes a difference? It seems like the "fullness" of the related field is determined before dehydrate?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [Amyth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15632203/571420) and [django-boundaryservice code](https://github.com/newsapps/django-boundaryservice), I got this to work by defaulting full to `True` and altering it in the `dehydrate` method on the *Related* PageResource:

```
class MapResource(gis_resources.ModelResource):
    page = fields.ToOneField('pages.api.PageResource', 'page', full=True)
```

pages.api:

```
class PageResource(ModelResource):
    ...

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        if not bundle.request.GET.get('full_pages'):
            bundle = bundle.data['resource_uri']
        return bundle
```

Comment: Yes, but part of the purpose of preventing `full` is to limit database queries for speed. I believe the `full` *database queries* will still be executed if this method is used. The correct data will be *returned*, but Tastypie will still do all the work to get the related objects (which takes time), then those objects will just be removed from the data.